# Replace String sequence using Recursion

Tags: java, string, recursion, replace

Java has the replace() and replaceAll() methods to replace parts/sequence of a string with a given new pattern. How does the internal of that function work? What if I had to write a function that inputs a string, OldPattern, NewPattern and replaces every occurrence of OldPattern with the NewPattern **recursively** without using RegEx?
I have done the following code using iteration for String input and it seems to work. What if the input is a characterArray instead of a string?

```
  public String replaceOld(String aInput, String aOldPattern, String aNewPattern)
        {
             if ( aOldPattern.equals("") ) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Old pattern must have content.");
             }

             final StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
             int startIdx = 0;
             int idxOld = 0;
             while ((idxOld = aInput.indexOf(aOldPattern, startIdx)) >= 0) {
               result.append( aInput.substring(startIdx, idxOld) );
               result.append( aNewPattern );

               //reset the startIdx to just after the current match, to see
               //if there are any further matches
               startIdx = idxOld + aOldPattern.length();
             }
             //the final chunk will go to the end of aInput
             result.append( aInput.substring(startIdx) );
             return result.toString();
          }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. You seem to have solved your problem, an converting a character array to a String is trivial.

Comment: If your code works fine, then you can convert the char array input to String by using the `toString()` function, perform the above analysis and while returning the modified string convert it back to char array by using the `toCharAprray()` function.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this using recursion. I have solved this only by using a loop/ iterative method. It was an interview question and they demanded a recursive solution without using any of the replace/ replaceall methods.

Answer (score 4):

> Java has the replace() and replaceAll() methods to replace parts/sequence of a string with a given new pattern.

To be precise, these methods create new strings with the relevant characters replaced.  A Java String is immutable.

> How does the internal of that function work?

That's too complicated to explain in detail here.  (And the details actually may vary from one implementation to the next).  Your best bet is to read the source code of the relevant library classes for yourself.  (The source code is distributed as part of your JDK, and your Java IDE should be able to show it to you.  Alternatively, a Google search will find it for you on the web.)

> What if I had to write a function that inputs a string, OldPattern, NewPattern and replaces every occurrence of OldPattern with the NewPattern recursively without using RegEx?

Well if you are talking about doing pattern match / replace without using the `Pattern` class, then yes that *would* be tricky ... not to mention that it would be pointless.

(A recursive solution could be dangerous.  Consider this problem: "recursively replace all instances of "a" with "ba" in "a".  What should the result be?  Should you even be trying to do this?)

---

Assuming that the arguments are simple strings (not patterns as you describe them) then here's a recursive solution (not tested):

```
public String replace1(String in, String target, String replacement) {
    if (target.isEmpty()) {
        return in;
    }
    int pos = in.indexOf(target);
    if (pos < 0) {
        return in;
    }
    String updated = in.substring(0, pos) + replacement + 
                     in.substring(pos + target.length());
    return replace1(updated, target, replacement);
}
```

That solves<sup>1</sup> the version of the problem where you want the replacement to be recursive; i.e. where you want to substitute instances of `target` that inserted by the replacement process.  If you don't want to do that, then:

```
public String replace2(String in, String target, String replacement) {
    if (target.isEmpty()) {
        return in;
    }
    int pos = in.indexOf(target);
    if (pos < 0) {
        return in;
    }
    return in.substring(0, pos) + replacement + 
                     replace2(in.substring(pos + target.length()),
                             target, replacement);
}
```

Note that these are most likely *less* efficient than your original iterative solution. Even ignoring all of the string copying that is going on.  Java doesn't do tail-call optimization.

---

<sup>1 - If you call `replace1` with pathological arguments, you will get a stack overflow.  For example `replace1("ab", "b", "b")`</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A very interesting point indeed, but the question for the interview demands you to do it recursively without using replace or pattern matching. Let's assume you are allowed pattern matching, how would you do that recursivelt? You could have any number of characters to match and replace.

Comment: If an interviewer is demanding that you solve a problem recursively, then he is probably a poor interviewer.  And if that is reflective of the company as a whole, you probably don't want to work for them.  But if you really, really need that job, you probably need to ask for a few hours to work on the problem ... 'cos it will take at least that for a minimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public static String replaceOld(String aInput, String aOldPattern, String aNewPattern, int i) {
    i = aInput.indexOf(aOldPattern, i);
    if (i == -1) {
        return aInput;
    }
    aInput = aInput.substring(0, i) + aNewPattern + aInput.substring(i + aOldPattern.length());
    return replaceOld(aInput, aOldPattern, aNewPattern, i + aNewPattern.length());
}
```

note that param `i` is used for optimization, so that indexOf does not scan from pos 0 every time. And it also solves "recursively replace all instances of "a" with "ba" in "a" problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your recursive solution is perfect!

Comment: But unfortunately it uses the replace method. I'm looking for a pure algorithmic solution using recursion.

Comment: If you are allowed to use substring then try my update

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this method will answer your question.

```
  static int indexOf(char[] string, char[] pattern, int startIndex) {
     int index = startIndex;
     while(true) {
         while(index < string.length && string[index] != pattern[0]) index++;
         if(index >= string.length || index+pattern.length > string.length) return -1;
         boolean match = true;
         for(int i = 1; i < pattern.length; i++) {
             if(string[index+i] != pattern[i]) {
                 match = false;
                 break;
             }
         }
         if(match) return index;
         else index += 1;
     }
  }
```

If you want a recursive replace method, use this

```
static String replace(String string, String pattern, String replacement) {
  int index = string.indexOf(pattern);
  if(index < 0) return string;
  int endIndex = index+pattern.length();
  return string.substring(0, index) + replacement +
      replace(string.substring(endIndex), pattern, replacement);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution is again very similar to what I have done except for the boolean check. I was looking for a recursive solution which is imo faster and impressive to code in an interview (say).